# How to get a value from other application and write it to a file?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a simple app with no UI, that will take data from another app and store it in output file using C#. That's all. How can I make:
1. Open the process
2. Find the value "X"
 2.1 Find the value "Y"
 2.2 Find the value "Z"
3. Write values to a file "C:\output.txt"
4. Update every 1000ms for example.

Here are two codes I hardly managed to run. 
**Reading from app:**

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public class MemoryRead
{
    const int PROCESS_WM_READ = 0x0010;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess, 
      int lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    public static void Main()
    {
        Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0]; 
        IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id); 

        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[24];    

        ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, 0x0001BA5B0, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);

        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer) + 
           " (" + bytesRead.ToString() + "bytes)");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

**Write to a file:**

```
class WriteTextFile
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] lines = { "X", "Y", "Z", };
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"O:\CS\output.txt", lines);

    }
}
```

2 question: 
 1. How do I "connect" these two codes
 2. How do I make the program refresh output every 1sec/2sec/300msec?

Thanks for any help!
P.S. If you know any existing app that will do exact same thing - it will be just OK for me.

**UPDATE:**
Finally made two pieces working together!

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

class Program
{

const int PROCESS_WM_READ = 0x0010;
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess, 
      int lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    static void Main()
    {
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("O:\\out.txt"))
    {
        Console.SetOut(writer);
        Act();
    }
    }

    static void Act()
 {
        Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0]; 
        IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id); 

        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[24]; 

      ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, 0x0021AAD0, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);


        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer));

    }
}
```

The code does what I need but only once: it reads the value and stores it in .txt. If the notepad's value is updated, the .txt content will remain unchanged until the program is restarted. How can I make it update over and over with no restarting the program?
C'mon guys, I'm half way there!!

Comment: Few options... 

1. Add a polling setting to your app.config and wrap your code in a loop, and use a timeout at the end of the loop with the polling setting.

2. Skip the loop and create a Scheduled Task that runs the program every X minutes.

Comment: Option#2 is quite handy! Let me try!

Comment: @ragerory Option#2 is not suitable for me because scheduler loops the launch in 1 minute. And I need to make the loop about 0,3secs...

Comment: #1 should suffice then.

Answer (score 0):

Create a scheduled task that runs the program on an interval.

Edit...

```
static void Main() 
{
    var totalRunTime = TimeSpan.FromDays(1); 
    var elapsed = 0;
    while (elapsed < totalRunTime.TotalMilliseconds) 
    { 
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("O:\\out.txt")) 
        { 
            Console.SetOut(writer); 
            Act(); 
        } 
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(350);
        elapsed += 350;
    }
}
```

Comment: Scheduled task has 1 minute minimum interval, while I need something around 350ms. app.config works fine, but is it possible to modify the code without adding external files? Maybe `for (;;)` construction will solve my problem.

Comment: I was suggesting putting the setting in your app.config that way it's not hardcoded, but my answer is the same, you wrap it in a loop (maybe a while (time < totalRunTime)) and add a timeout that you want (`Threading.Thread.Sleep(350)`)

Comment: I'm absolute newbie (started C# this morning), can you post exact code for it?

Comment: Just started this morning?

`var totalRunTime = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
var elapsed = 0;
while (elapsed < totalRunTime.TotalMilliseconds)
{ 
    // Do your actions here
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(350);
    elapsed += 350;
}`

You're probably going to run into conflicts though when you keep streaming that file every 350 milliseconds.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can not figure out where to put your code in my example. Can you insert it in exact spots?

Comment: Put it in your Main, and put your using block inside the while loop. You can't expect people to just write all your code for you without at least trying to figure it out. I'm kind of shocked you just started C# this morning and this is the question you are asking.

Comment: Hey-hey-hey! I almost did 80% of my code myself. Only trying to get some help with loop. Of course I did some tries to put your code but failed. I'm sure it will take 4 minutes of your time max. This: `static void Main()
var totalRunTime = TimeSpan.FromDays(1); 
var elapsed = 0;
    { 
 while (elapsed < totalRunTime.TotalMilliseconds) {
 using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("O:\\out.txt"))
 {
     Console.SetOut(writer);
     Act();
  
 }
  }
  Threading.Thread.Sleep(350); elapsed += 350; 
  }`

does not work.

Comment: Just having a hard time believing you wrote all that code above after only learning C# for a few hours, but couldn't figure out this loop, which should be the easiest part.